# How to create rectangular 2d array in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to create a minesweeper clone for school and looking to create a variable board size, the below code works to create a 2d minefield but I get an arrayIndex out of bounds error when columns != rows. Any help would be appreciated. Amateur code so any other advice is welcome.

```
public void genBoard(int columns, int rows) {
    board = new Tile[rows][columns];
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < board[y].length + 1; x++) {
            board[x][y] = new Tile(x, y, 0, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You’ve swapped rows and cols. You create and array `[rows][cols]` (swapping method argument order for some reason. You then loop `y` over `rows` and `x` over cols. Finally you assign `[x][y]` - i.e. `[cols][rows]`.

Comment: Please don’t edit your question to substantively change the question being asked once you have answers.

Comment: `x < board[y].length + 1` - why +1 ?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Very sorry, I just noticed I had copied an older segment of code, the code currently up is what I have been having issues with, at this point should I delete the question and create a new post?

Comment: I would ask a new question, yes. This question has an upvoted answer which refers to the code you originally post. Please take a lesson away here - take at least as much effort asking your question as you expect people to take answering it; please proof read your questions!

Answer (score 2):

```
x < board[y].length + 1;
```

should be

```
x < board[y].length;
```

That is what is causing the index out of bound error.

But also, `board[x][y]` should be `board[y][x]`